# How to replace $$ in javascript

Tags: javascript

When I try to replace `$$` using `replace()` it will replace to single `$` only.

```
var abc = "T"
abc.replace("T","A$$B")
"A$B"
```

I require output as `"A$$B"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the language is called JavaScript.

Secondly, you have to "escape" every literal `$` with another `$` because they're usually used to backreference submatches:

```
'this is a test'.replace(/(.)s/g, '_$1s');
  //=> 'thi_is _is a t_est'
```

Note that the `$1` in the replacement string is replaced by whatever `(.)` matched in the original regex, the first capture group.

So, you would use:

```
abc.replace('T', 'A$$$$B');
```

Two `$`s, each escaped by another `$`.

If you need to do this automatically (i.e. you have a variable with the replacement string already), you can use:

```
var replStr = 'A$$B';
abc.replace('T', replStr.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$'));  // replace all $ with $$
```

Comment: does $ alone has any special meaning?

Comment: var abc = "{Univ}"

var lUniv = "FOCAN$$FFO|E0USA$$FST|E0CAN$$FST|FOAL$L$BAS|ETEXG$XTSE"

abc.replace("{Univ}",lUniv.replace('$','$$$$')) Output will be ..
"FOCAN$$FFO|E0USA$FST|E0CAN$FST|FOAL$L$BAS|ETEXG$XTSE" Output is ... it will not replace when you have more than one occurrences

Comment: @Satish To replace all occurrences use regex with `g`-global flag. `lUniv.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$')`

Comment: @Tushar - It works in my case. Thanks a lot guys for your help

Answer (score 2):

From Docs of [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter), `$$` is used to insert `$`.

[image]

To insert `$` two $, use `$$$`

```
abc.replace("T", "A$$$B"); `$$` ==> `$` and `$` ==> `$`
```

Or, you can also use `$$$$`

```
abc.replace("T", "A$$$$");
```

Comment: good. +1 for the effort. I also tried to get the info. But how come $$$ inputs 2 $ symbols ? like the demo in Rahul Tripathi 's answer.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi The First two `$$` are replaced by a single dollar as the Docs say. The last `$` has no special meaning, so used as string literal.